# Issue with BackProjection and Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, back-projection

I am trying to implement a backprojection algorithm with opencv to detect hands. This algorithm is composed from multiple sources. I have tried multiple methods such as morphologies and adding backgroundSubtraction to the projection to try to get a better result.I looked online too. However, I keep on getting the pic below. Does anyone have suggestions on what I am possibly doing wrong?

-Thank you

Here is my code with just the backProjection:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#module for esc keyMap on my computer
import keyMappings as kM

#set up webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1000) 
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)

#read a picture of a hand from my desktop
Hand = cv2.imread('/home/lie/Desktop/handPic.jpg')

#convert HSV and calc Histogram of this Pic
hsvHand = cv2.cvtColor(Hand, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsvHand)
roihist = cv2.calcHist([hsvHand], [0,1], None, [180,256],[0,180,0,256])
cv2.normalize(roihist,roihist,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

#while not pressing esc
while cv2.waitKey(30) != kM.esc:

  #take pic convert HSV
  _,frame = cap.read() 
  hsvt = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

  #backproject
  dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsvt],[0,1],roihist,[0,180,0,256],1)


  #filtering
  disc = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
  cv2.filter2D(dst,-1,disc,dst)



  #threshold
  ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(dst,50,255,0)


   #find contours in thresholded pic
   contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


   ci =0
   max_area =0

   if len(contours)!=0:
      #find max contour
      for i in range(len(contours)):
        cnt = contours[i]
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if(area>max_area):
            max_area = area
            ci =i
      #create hull around contour
      cnt = contours[ci]
      hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)

 #Code to draw contours and show pic is ommited
```

This is the image used to help recognize a hand:
[image: Image read in as Picture of a Hand]

This is the thresholded picture:
[image]

The picture obviously shows not much of the hand and a lot of noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a very very long time since this post, and frankly I'm a bit surprised nobody responded to you. Although I'm quite sure you've found the answer/alternative solution, for the benefit of others I'll answer this.

What you are observing is directly caused by the number of bins that you are using in your H-S histogram. A larger number of bins means that you will be more finely representing skin, meaning that your eventual histogram will not be able to build up a "trend" of skin. You should absolutely reduce the number of bins. In my experience, about anything between 8 and 12 for both Hue and Saturation channels works well.

However, doing this isn't going to guarantee a very nice backprojected image. You still have a major issue and that is you're using the entire hand template to generate your histogram. As it is, the template contains a lot of skin, but a lot of area around the hand which is not skin. The eventual histogram that you generate will represent background as well. In my experience with this (and I've got a lot of it), even relatively small amounts of noise filtering into the eventual histogram will cause large amounts of noise in your backprojected image. Keeping background in your histogram to a minimum is key. So consider rather taking a small area inside your hand template and generating your histogram only on that. I modified your code as below and it works like a dream on my config.

Note that I made a few changes e.g. this just uses the button 'q' to quit, and the path to the template has been modified, etc. It is mostly the same.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


#set up webcam

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
#cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

#read a picture of a hand from my desktop
Hand = cv2.imread('handPic.jpg')
hh,hw, __ = Hand.shape
#convert HSV and calc Histogram of this Pic
hsvHand = cv2.cvtColor(Hand[220:292, 110:220], cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsvHand)
roihist = cv2.calcHist([hsvHand], [0,1], None, [12,12],[0,181,0,256])
#cv2.normalize(roihist,roihist,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

#while not pressing esc
while cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF != ord('q'):

  #take pic convert HSV
  _,frame = cap.read()
  hsvt = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

  #backproject
  dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsvt],[0,1],roihist,[0,180,0,256],1)


  #filtering

  # ret, dst = cv2.threshold(dst,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

  disc = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
  cv2.filter2D(dst,-1,disc,dst)


  cv2.imshow("Skin Areas", dst)
```